# CentOS and Switching Unix Shells

Tags: bash, shell, csh

I am using a VMWare Virtual Machine with CentOS installed.

I am using BASH shell now but need to run an application that requires C Shell.

Can a person just switch shells ?  Will you need to reinstall all softwares ?  Will existing software works ?  Is is just that easy to switch shells ?

The program I need has an install script written in C Shell and the program requires C Shell to run.

Comment: You do not need to switch shells in order to run scripts under a different shell. Assuming `/bin/csh` is installed on the system, all you need to do is either have the first line of the script read `#!/bin/csh` and have execute permissions turned on on the script or explicitly execute the script using `csh scriptname`

Comment: If you type `csh` to your bash shell, does it give you an error or does it give you a prompt that ends in `%` ?

Comment: I will try it and let you know.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

An application (proper) won't *require* the C Shell; a wrapper script that uses csh syntax will require the C shell, in which case, it should have a first line that says so:

```
#!/bin/csh
```

or

```
#!/bin/tcsh
```

or similar.

You can execute that script from bash, and without having to switch your login shell to csh.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change the shell of your own user with the utility called `chsh` which should be installed by default on CentOS system. The syntax would be:

```
chsh -s /bin/csh OR /bin/tcsh
```

Before doing this, make sure C Shell is installed in your system, it should show in `/etc/shells` as /`bin/csh` (or `/bin/tcsh`). If it is not there, I am pretty sure you can install it by simply doing `yum install tcsh` (On my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, it is available as `csh`)

You need to log out completely from the system and then log back again to make these changes take effect.

If it is just a script that you want to run, just add the shebang header in the top of the script as `#!/bin/tcsh` or `#!/bin/csh` depending under what name it is available inside `/etc/shells`. `shebang header` is the first line in a script.

Comment: Thank you. Problem is I have to run scripts to access this module of software everytime I use it in another software running under BASH. So everytime I want to use these modules I have to run a script: % source ./xxx.csh in order to use this module of software. Can I tell the command line to just run a cshell script under bash shell to run this script and then go back to bash ? Thank you for your patience with my questions. To be clear, this is a subset of software created with and using cshell scripts running under bash shell with main software running this subset under bash shell.

Comment: Can I just say #!/bin/csh at the command line and then run the script in c shell and then go back to bash shell somehow ?

Comment: If this is temporary, and `shebang header` does not suffice the requirement, you can run your script from `bash` shell as: `$ /bin/tcsh yourscript.csh` (`$` denoting the bash shell). This will run your script using `csh` and once the script exits, you'll have your `bash` shell back at the prompt.

Comment: Also, the script requires an environment variable to be set.  Can I simultaneously set an environment variable in c and bash shells ?  Can I set a cshell environment variable while in bash shell ?  or will script running in c shell do that itself if the script tells it to ?  Once environment variable set will it still be seen by bash shell if set in c shell ?  This is confusing.

Comment: I've never done this personally, but you can set your environment variables in the configuration file for `csh` (generally at `~/.cshrc`). When the `csh` shell runs to execute your script, I am sure it would read it's env variables from csh configuration file

Comment: Do I edit the ~/.cshrc in the Bash shell ?

Comment: You can do that, it won't matter under what shell you edit this file

Answer (score 0):

`exec tcsh` replaces the current running shell with `tcsh`. and then `exec bash` would replace the current shell with `bash` (preserving whatever environment variables are already set, for better or worse), if the software requires that various `source foo.cshrc` commands be used to load environment settings and so forth for that application.

```
% exec bash
bash-4.2$ exec tcsh
$ exec zsh
%
```

whether software works is a rather difficult question to answer without details (see: the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem))

the shell change can be made more permanent with `chsh` as pointed out by others.